# Laravel 5.8 register redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8, still new to PHP and Laravel. When I register, it returns the user in JSON format which is normal from the Register Users.php register function. However, I have a `redirectTo()` function which should take care of the redirect and redirect the user to some pages a specified, but it's not working. I've tried overriding the `redirectPath()` function as well which isn't working.

The redirect works perfectly for the login controller.

Any solution or pointers would be appreciated. See RegisterController below.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //public $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected function redirectPath()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->role;
        if ($role === 'candidate') {
            return '/candidate_dashboard';
        } elseif ($role === 'employer') {
            return '/employer_dashboard';
        } elseif ($role === 'contractor') {
            return '/contractor_dashboard';
        }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        try {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'role' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
        } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException  $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
    }

    protected function create(Request $data)
    {
        try {
            return User::create([
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                'role' => $data['role'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share your Registercontroller please

Comment: I've added the controller, kindly check it out

Comment: Your `create()` method returns just that newly created user instance. Remove returns from that line and add `return redirect()->to($redirectTo)` after, just before catch block.

Comment: Thank you, I thought of this earlier but wasn't sure how laravel works.